# Watch a sql table continuously for a particular value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i was trying to connect a local machine with my web application.i need to get some data from local machine  and insert it into my online table.User clicks a button and a new column is  added to a online table named request which has status "new" in the beginning.i went for sql dependency which i installed as a windows service in local machine and it check the request table for any new insert.the service fetches some data from the local machine and posts it to the online database and change the status field in request table to "updated".

Now my problem is how can i notify my website that required data has been inserted in the table?? i need to watch the request table continuously until the value in the status column  changes to updated.can i go for thread or timer ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write an INSERT trigger in the live database which your website is using.

Use another Table RequestUpdates and write an INSERT trigger that adds a value to the table RequestUpdates in the live database.

Design your website to load the RequestUpdates table.
And when the user loggs in and Requests have been viewed, change the status in the live table to viewed.

In this way new requests will be shown that are not viewed the next time.

Comment: i need to watch the request table continuously all these events take place in a single button click